# Android: Stop EditText from going outside of tablerow

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, tablerow, android-tablelayout

So i have a tablelayout in android with some table rows. In each row i have a textview and an edittext. My setup looks like:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:stretchColumns="3" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/vnosnopolje" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Up. ime"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/uporabnisko_ime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/vnosnopolje" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Geslo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/geslo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

It all works fine. But when i enter a longer text into textview my edittext goes outside the table row. So it looks like it doesn't end. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just you set in TextView and EditText Views

`android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: That way it puts my textview in 2 rows. I't looks realy stupid. And if i add android_singeline=true. It makes string look like myStrin... It removes some characters and add ...

Comment: Now i set weight to textview to 0.001 and edittext to 1 and now it wroks like it should!! Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can force the width to stay in the table using the formatter.  You can read more about it here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html