# How to control EditText scrolling in dynamically added TableLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-tablelayout

I am programmatically adding a TableLayout to a parent LinearLayout in Android. The table has one row with two columns; an EditText and a Button. I am also specifying that the EditText can be stretched to fill the width while the Button remains constant in size (kind of like an input-append component). Everything is fine until I populate a long text as the value for the EditText, which seems to make it stretch so that the whole value can be displayed (rather than being ellipsized). This of course means the button is pushed off the right edge, making it unusable.

**The added dynamic layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0">
   <TableRow>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/added_text"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text=""
            androin:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:enabled="false"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/added_button"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"                
            android:src="@drawable/minus"/>     
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**The code that populates the EditText and adds the table:**

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent); // LinearLayout
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View dynamic = li.inflate(R.layout.dynamic, null);
EditText et = (EditText) dynamic.findViewById(R.id.added_text);
et.setText("Some very long text...");
parent.addView(dynamic, 1);
```

What I want is simple; just to ellipsize the EditText value so that the added view honors the parent width.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding the following to the EditText above solved it.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Found it here actually:

[Android: Stop EditText from going outside of tablerow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622978/android-stop-edittext-from-going-outside-of-tablerow?rq=1)